# UIPageControl is clickable

Tags: bug, ios-app

On tips an tricks you don't handle page control click. Dot is changed, but not page

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)